# How to connect AWS RDS to AWS EKS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a AWS EKS cluster on which I have 2 pods running; one pod is a redis cache and the other is a GraphQL API. I also have a AWS RDS (mysql) instance which my GraphQL API is trying to communicate to.

However when I view the logs of the GraphQL API, this is the error I am receiving:

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at PoolConnection._handleTimeoutError (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:189:17)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7) {
  errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  fatal: true
}
```

The interesting thing is that I am able to successfully connect to the rds database from mysql workbench...

I am 67% sure that it is because of the way I have configured my security groups for the eks cluster.

Here is a screenshot of the inbound rules for the eks security group:
[image: inbound rules for the eks security group]

Here is a screenshot of the outbound rules for the eks security group:
[image: outbound rules for the eks security group]

Here is a screenshot of the inbound rules for the rds security group:
[image: inbound rules for the rds security group]

Here is a screenshot of the outbound rules for the rds security group:
[image: outbound rules for the rds security group]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What about your RDS security group?

Comment: I have added the screenshots for the rds and eks security groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the RDS security group, you don't allow EKS to connect by MySQL protocol.
What is the IP 175.34.53.139/32 mean? If they are in the same VPC, they will use private IP instead of public IP.

Comment: Thank you so much Ash! I had to change the 175.43.53.139/32 to 0.0.0.0/0 and boom! Again, thanks so much!

Comment: @georgewashingmachine Don't allow from 0.0.0.0/0 as it's less secure. Instead allow from the EKS security group.

Comment: according to @jordanm, you can use the CIDR or private subnet instead

Comment: I meant that you can use the security group as the source instead of a CIDR in the security group rule.